# Setting "active" className for the menu user selected in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks, state

[image]

Just like the screenshot above, I am using Semantic-UI where the selected menu gets highlighted.
As my code below, I've set state to whichever menu the user clicks on. My code below works fine, but I think this is inefficient ways to write code since I am basically calling two functions everytime I render just to change the switch out the class names.

Would there be any better way to achieve this?

Please advise.

```
const Navigation = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("Comments");

  const onSelection = (e) => {
    setSelected(e.target.textContent);
  };

  const commentActive = () => {
    return selected === "Comments" ? "active" : "";
  };

  const searchActive = () => {
    return selected === "Search" ? "active" : "";
  };

  return (
    <div className="ui secondary pointing menu">
      <a className={`item ${commentActive()}`} onClick={(e) => onSelection(e)}>
        Comments
      </a>
      <a className={`item ${searchActive()}`} onClick={(e) => onSelection(e)}>
        Search
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't hardcode the boolean conditions `selected === 'Comments'` as its bug prone, because if you decide to change the anchor's context without changing the condition you may have a bug: `target.textContent !== 'Comments'`;

Instead use enums:

```
const NAV_SECTIONS = {
  COMMENTS: "comments",
  SEARCH: "search",
};

const Navigation = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(NAV_SECTIONS.COMMENTS);

  return (
    <div className="ui secondary pointing menu">
      <a
        className={`item ${selected === NAV_SECTIONS.COMMENTS ? "active" : ""}`}
        onClick={() => setSelect(NAV_SECTIONS.COMMENTS)}
      >
        {/* We changed the content and the code didn't break */}
        My Cool Comments
      </a>
      <a
        className={`item ${selected === NAV_SECTIONS.SEARCH ? "active" : ""}`}
        onClick={() => setSelect(NAV_SECTIONS.SEARCH)}
      >
        My Best Search
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: As someone just getting started with programming, I was literally awed by your solution. Thank you very much.